# Azure: MongoDB replica sets initialization error (local.oplog.rs is not empty)

Tags: mongodb, azure

When initializing MongoDB replica sets on Azure dev i get following error:

> Command 'replSetInitiate' failed: local.oplog.rs is not empty on the initiating member.  cannot initiate. (response: { "errmsg" : "local.oplog.rs is not empty on the initiating member.  cannot initiate.", "ok" : 0.0 })

I have tried cleanup localstorage on recycle, but it does not help.

I used source that provided by 10gen: [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-azure/blob/master/ReplicaSets/README.md) and [blog post](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+on+Azure)

**UPDATE:**

That error appear in console after calling RunInitializeCommandLocally method (happens for each ReplicaSetRole)

Then i try to create MongoServer and each instance in it has Disconnected state.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There was no problem at all. This exception is normal behavior. Just need to wait couple of seconds and replica set will be initialized.

*Note: use mongo.exe to check status of replica set.*

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy the mongodb azure package, RunInitializeCommandLocally is called as part of the startup, which initialises the replica set. So the replica set is already initialised.